# Want's to design push mechanism using flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Thanks for this nice information. I am looking for socket connection to build push mechanism from server to flex application. 
Scenario.
1. There will be one server and static IP attach to IT. 
2. I want to send some information to flex application user when ever triggering happen at server end.
3. Trigger can be happen by many ways like IVRS system, web service or windows server.
4. Once it triggers, Information has to be send to specific user not for all user.

can anybody knows about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at web sockets?

Comment: I looked but did not find anything suitable to my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push is usually implemented by having a long running open socket connection between server and client.  Client sits there listening for a response on the socket.  You should be able to do this in Flex with a Loader of some sort or an httpservice, you just need to figure out how to prevent a time out (IDK if thats possible, ive never tried).  Add an event listener for a response from the server and perform your operation there.
Have you tried any ways yet?  Any luck?